# Android x86 (7.1, TV / Leanback) not booting on a Virtual Machine with GooglePackageInstaller

Tags: boot, android-x86, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine running Android x86 (7.1, TV / Leanback 'edition'), and I'm attempting to install GApps (from OpenGApps). The installation worked perfectly except for one app - GooglePackageInstaller. When this app is installed, the boot appears to hang. I managed to get some dmesg logs of the failed boot: https://pastebin.com/UUn6Pup0

For reference, here is logs of a successful boot: https://pastebin.com/sVxQVRYC

The logs appear to be very similar until the successful one appears to initialise:
`[    0.774709] init: init first stage started!` (line 408), but this line never appears on the unsuccessful boot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: If more information is required, please comment and I'll attempt to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable 3D Acceleration in the display settings for your box.